# Is there a way to send keyboard input to multiple Terminal windows?

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to open up two Terminal.app windows and let them mirror each other. This would work much like the Split Pane function in 10.6, but in two separate windows.

I'd like this for demonstration purposes running dual displays, one being my laptop, the other a projector, without having to mirror the entire desktop.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate.  See http://superuser.com/questions/82530/sending-one-key-stroke-to-two-windows-ubuntu/82545#82545

Answer (score 0):

While you'd have to be opening up a different shell/session, this would accomplish what you're asking as far as I can tell: 
via @marczak, http://www.brock-family.org/gavin/macosx/csshX.html